# Saving a file to a restricted drive

Tags: vba

I've been able to successfully save a document to a shared drive/folder, using ActiveDocument.SaveAs, giving the path and file name. I've been tasked to save a document to a folder in a drive that I do not have access to... nor will the users sending and saving this document. My question is.. is this possible?

This works...

' Gather information for file name
        Dim fname As String
        fname = "CMA Payment & Refund Investigation Form"

```
    Dim fname1 As String
    fname1 = ActiveDocument.FormFields("PCID").Result

    Dim fname2 As String
    fname2 = Date$

' Save document
ActiveDocument.SaveAs "C:\Test Forms\CMA Payment and Refund\" & fname & " - " & fname1 & "-" & fname2 & ".docm"
```

However, when I switch the drive and folder names it doesn't.

I receive Run-time error '5152'
This is not a valid file name. ( It is)
*Check the path to make sure it was typed correctly. (I did)
*Select a file from a list of files and folders. (I don't have access to the files, but was given a screenshot of the path.)

Comment: If you don't have access to the drive, why do you think it might be possible for you to save something to it? Isn't that _accessing_ the drive, by definition?

Comment: That's my thought... but I've received conflicting information from different people... some say it's not possible, while others do. That's why I've asked... to get an outside opinion. Thanks Jeff.

Comment: This is not vbscript. Do you mean VBA? Please use the appropriate tag.

Comment: Whoops, thanks Geert. Good catch.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin is correct, If you don't have modify access to a location, you won't be able to save anything to it. If you don't have read access you won't even be able to see it. You will need to contact whoever manages drive permissions and get added in. Then try and rerun the code and see what happens.

Comment: Strictly speaking, it _is_ possible, by running as administrator - but then the Windows UAC prompts for credentials for an identity that _has_ access to the drive in question.

Comment: Right, I get that if permission is given or running as admin.... However, that is not what the requestor wants. The people that are requesting the form be saved on this drive, want to be able to keep the access restricted. It seems the answer is for them to create a folder on a shared drive that everyone has access to or... it's emailed and then they can manually place it in the designated folder.

Comment: @Courtney that's an action for your network or systems administrator to create such a folder with the correct permissions. Once the destination location is properly set up and everyone can see it, your code should work with no issues.

Comment: I thought that was the direction, this was going to need to go... Thanks PeterT!